# How to myke the MySQL Slow Query Log respect the long_query_time?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-slow-query-log

My [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) is full of queries, that should not be written there, e.g.:

```
# Time: 2022-03-11T12:23:29.258308Z
# User@Host: ...
# Schema: ...
# Query_time: 0.022791  Lock_time: 0.000201  Rows_sent: 1000  Rows_examined: 1000  Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 115518
use ...;
SET timestamp=1647001409;
SELECT * FROM `my_table` LIMIT 0,1000;
```

The query time is `0.022791` seconds. And the [`long_query_time`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) is `5.000000`:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `variable_name` = "long_query_time";
+-----------------+----------+
| Variable_name   | Value    |
+-----------------+----------+
| long_query_time | 5.000000 |
+-----------------+----------+
```

**What's going wrong here? How to avoid such a "spam" in the Slow Query Log?**

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+---------------+
| VERSION()     |
+---------------+
| 5.7.36-39-log |
```

Comment: What is the value of `log_queries_not_using_indexes`?

Comment: (And this is one reason I recommend setting that to OFF.)